# Leaflet: how to affect all markers on a map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Basically, I have several markers on my Leaflet map. I am using jQuery. At the moment, if I want to fill a marker's popup with AJAX, I have to use this code:

```
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
var marker2 = L.marker([51.49, -0.09]).addTo(map);

marker.on("click", function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Home/transactionForm",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(ajaxresult)
        {
            marker.setPopupContent(ajaxresult);
        },
        error: function (ajaxresult) {
            alert("Filling the popup failed!");
        }
    });
});

marker2.on("click", function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Home/transactionForm",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(ajaxresult)
        {
            marker2.setPopupContent(ajaxresult);
        },
        error: function (ajaxresult) {
            alert("Filling the popup failed!");
        }
    });
});
```

Obviously, this is far from ideal. In jQuery, this would be simple:

```
$("#map").on("click", "#marker", function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Home/transactionForm",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(ajaxresult)
    {
        $(this).setPopupContent(ajaxresult);
    },
    error: function (ajaxresult) {
        alert("Filling the popup failed!");
    }
});
```

How do I do this? I know my map's ID, but can't figure out what ID Leaflet assigns to its markers, popups and other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet doesn't add different ids to each marker/popups. It just adds the appropriate class to each element. So those elements are not meant to be accessed with jQuery selectors.

If you want to set the popup content with ajax with the same url (as you are doing here), why not just add all the markers to a list, iterate through it and then set the event handler for each marker in that list. Something like this:

```
var markersArray = [];
markersArray.push(marker1);
markersArray.push(marker2);
for (var marker in markersArray) {
marker.on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Home/transactionForm",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(ajaxresult)
        {
            marker.setPopupContent(ajaxresult);
        },
        error: function (ajaxresult) {
            alert("Filling the popup failed!");
        }
    });
});
}
```